# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at signUpValidate (fhe.js:26) at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have users enter their information for signing up. I am coming across an error and it looks like I know what the error is but I do not know how to fix it. Someone help, please.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at signUpValidate (fhe.js:26) at HTMLInputElement.onclick

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">`enter code here`
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fhe.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fheCss.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up Page</title>
    <h1>Family Home Evening</h1>
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
</head>
<body class="backgroundPic">
<form class="mySignUpForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="signUpUserName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{8,20}$" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="signUpPassword" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Verify Password" name="signUpVerPassword" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required/><br><br>

    <input type="button" value="Sign up" id="signup" onclick="signUpValidate()"/><br><br>
    <a href="login.html">Back to Login</a><br><br>
</form>

<h4>Username: Username must be between 8 to 20 character<br><br>
    Password: Password must contain 1 uppercase, lowercase and number</h4><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
var signUpAttempt = 3;
function signUpValidate() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var signUpUserName = document.getElementById("signUpUserName").value;
    var signUpPassword = document.getElementById("signUpPassword").value;
    var signUpVerPassword = document.getElementById("signUpVerPassword").value;
    if (firstName == "Ashish" &&
        lastName == "Pokhrel" &&
        signUpUserName == "ashishpokhrel" &&
        signUpPassword == "ashishpokhrel69" &&
        signUpVerPassword == "ashishpokhrel69"){
        alert("Signed Up Successful");
        window.location = "login.html";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        signUpAttempt --;
        alert("Please fill out correct input." + "You have " + signUpAttempt + "attempt.");

        if(signUpAttempt == 0){
            document.getElementById("firstName").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("lastName").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("signUpUserName").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("signUpPassword").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("signUpVerPassword").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("signup").disabled = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't have id field in the input elements, but you are getting the DOM value using document.getElementById.. add field id="firstName" for firstName field and add respective id fields to other inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `document.getElementById()` to fetch the value from the form, but you haven't provided the `id` attribute in the input elements.

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" required/><br><br>
<input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" required/><br><br>
<input type="text" id="signUpUserName" placeholder="Username" name="signUpUserName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{8,20}$" required/><br><br>
<input type="text" id="signUpPassword" placeholder="Password" name="signUpPassword" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required/><br><br>
<input type="text" id="signUpVerPassword" placeholder="Verify Password" name="signUpVerPassword" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required/><br><br>
```

Comment: Oh ya, that fixed it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `document.getElementById` to get your elements, but you haven't defined IDs on the elements themselves (in the HTML). Note that an element's name is not the same as its ID.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are trying get `getElementById`, but you have no element with that ID, so you need to add an ID on all the input fields you are trying to get the data from

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">`enter code here`
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fhe.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fheCss.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up Page</title>
    <h1>Family Home Evening</h1>
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
</head>
<body class="backgroundPic">
<form class="mySignUpForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName"  id="firstName" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="signUpUserName" id="signUpPassword" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{8,20}$" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="signUpPassword" id="signUpPassword" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required/><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Verify Password" name="signUpVerPassword" id="signUpVerPassword" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" required/><br><br>

    <input type="button" value="Sign up" id="signup" onclick="signUpValidate()"/><br><br>
    <a href="login.html">Back to Login</a><br><br>
</form>

<h4>Username: Username must be between 8 to 20 character<br><br>
    Password: Password must contain 1 uppercase, lowercase and number</h4><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```